How to Submit Separate Actions from a Single Form Tag? (Django)
I have written the following code where a submit action with the value {{category.name}} unexpectedly triggers the "create" button in form_category, resulting in a "Please enter a name" message.
This approach worked fine in a previous project using the same logic. I've confirmed that the urls.py is properly set up. What could be the issue?
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    category name: {{ form_category }}
    <input type="submit" value="create" formaction="{% url 'mk_category' %}">
    <span> | </span>
    {% for category in categories %}
    <input type="submit" value="{{category.name}}" formaction="{% url 'index_with_category' category.id %}">
    {% endfor %}
</form>

Thank you very much for your help!
Wrapping each submit button in separate form tags resolves the issue. However, I plan to continue using multiple submit buttons within a single form in the future. I have checked urls.py multiple times and found no issues.
Please help me with this.

"triggers the "create" button" What do you mean by that? Do you have some JavaScript listening to the form submission event or the click event on the submit inputs? I don't see how the code you've shared will trigger that other button you speak of.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer is - you should define seperates names for your submits.
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <span>category name: {{ form_category }}</span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_create" value="create" formaction="{% url 'mk_category' %}" />
    <span> | </span>
    {% for category in categories %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_update_{{category.id}}" value="{{category.name}}" formaction="{% url 'index_with_category' category.id %}" />
    {% endfor %}
</form>

